# Check constraint in Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

This question is to understand and enhance my knowledge in pyspark Dataframes, I want to know a method to apply constraints , just like we apply in SQl. I have in mind to create df that has no null/duplicate  constraints on some columns.

2. How to enhance coding skills in pyspark (I have all the environments needed for it), please share some good links?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you can set non-nullable column in the schema definition, but afaik no duplicate is not possible in spark dataframes

Comment: Yes nullable=True is possible ! Thanks for sharing the information